# How to pass row of dataframe to a function in spark scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I want to take the input of each row of a dataframe and retun output as a map.I have written a below methood

```
def getV(str:String,colValues:Map[String,Any]):Any={
    var s= colValues.get("str") match {
      case Some(value) =>value
      case None =>None
    }
    return s
  }
  def setV(key:String,value:String,colValues:scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Any]):Unit={
    colValues(key)=value
  }

def returnNotEmptyCols_map(inputRow: Row): collection.mutable.Map[String,Any] = {
    implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)
    var colValues = inputRow.getValuesMap[Any](inputRow.schema.fieldNames)
    var mutMap = collection.mutable.Map(colValues.toSeq: _*)
    //Write my operations here------
    //print(getV("number",colValues))
    //setV("hey","there",mutMap)
   
    mutMap
    //return df

  }
```

However the problem I am facing is that I am calling this function from a dataframe using udf and hence the resulting output is in a column format

```
spark.udf.register("myFilterFunction", returnNotEmptyCols _)
    import spark.implicits._
    val df = Seq(
      (12, "bat"),
      (13, "mouse"),
      (14, "horse")
    ).toDF("number", "word")
    var dr=df.rdd.collect
    val newDF=df.withColumn("newcl",callUDF("myFilterFunction",struct(df.columns.map(df(_)) : _*)))
```

Is there any way where I can pass the row as an input to the methood returnNotEmptyCols_map
function and get oupput as a map(not as a column of a dataframe).
There's way we can do this using below link
[function to each row of Spark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329406/function-to-each-row-of-spark-dataframe)

But it is also a udf and resulting output in column format.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of UDF is to continue working with DataFrame. If you don't need DataFrame, you can run map on underlying rdd with your function as a parameter and get  rdd of the type your function returns.

`val rdd = df.rdd.map(returnNotEmptyCols_map)`

It doesn't work with Dataset.map, because of `Any`

Then you can do `rdd.collect` or whatever